# Bootstrap-vue with Vuelidate,how to stop validate the form at the initial state

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

we shouldn't have the form be validated when the form get in view .
after the user interacte with the inputs ,it's validation should be activated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to check if it's dirty or not:

```
<b-form-input
  v-model="name"
  @input="$v.name.$touch()"
  :state="$v.name.$dirty ? !$v.name.$error : null"
/>
```

If you don't want valid state (`is-valid` class), then:

```
<b-form-input
  v-model="name"
  @input="$v.name.$touch()"
  :state="!$v.name.$error && null"
/>
```

Comment: what is `$v` referring to?

Comment: $v is the validation results object.